# divisibility by 3 question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to show that $3|a(2a^2 + 7)$ where $a$ is an integer?

I know this can be proved by mathematical induction.But im searching for an argument like thing to show this

Comment: Do you some some modular arithmetic (i.e., sum/product modulo some integer)?

Comment: i just made something like this a(a^2+7)=3a(a^2+3)-a(a^2+2)

Comment: Are you sure you've entered the expression correctly? Consider $a = 1$. $3\not\mid 8$

Comment: amWhy is right: your expression is wrong, @user139296. Perhaps it must be $\;8\;$ instead of $\;7\;$ ...?

Answer (score 1):

$$a(a^2+7)=a(a^2-1)+8a\equiv8a\pmod 6$$ as $$a(a^2-1)=(a-1)a(a+1)$$ being product of $3$ consecutive integers is divisible by $3!=6$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}a(2a^2 + 7) &\equiv a(2a^2 - 2) \pmod 3\\
&= 2a(a^2 - 1)\pmod 3\\
&= 2(a-1)(a)(a+1) \pmod 3\end{align}$$

Now, at least one of $a-1,a,a+1$ must be divisible by $3$. (In general, $k$ must divide one and only one of $k$ consecutive integers). Hence,

$$a(2a^2 + 7)\equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

and therefore, $3 \mid a(2a^2 + 7)$ for all integers $a$.